# Adding gas/oil mixture into unmixed gas tank?

Tags: lawn-mower, gasoline

My wife accidentally added about a cup of gas/oil mixture (50:1) into our lawn mower which takes unmixed fuel. If she fills the rest of the tank with regular gas will there be any problems? Do I have to empty all the gas out?

The tank holds .6 gallons of fuel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be fine. The mixed gas will be diluted almost 10x if you fill the rest of the tank with fresh gas. The mower might be a little smokier than usual but you probably won't even notice.

If it makes you feel better you can keep topping up the tank with fresh gas as you use it, that will further dilute the oil. But personally I wouldn't bother.

Comment: It won't be a problem at all.